Flutter - Click part of RichText (specific TextSpan) from Widget Tests / UI Tests
Let's suppose you need to click the following TextSpan Text span in italic inside the Flutter widget tree running Widget UI tests.
This makes specific parts of a text clickable in flutter integration testing.
The UI looks as follows:
RichText(
  key: Key("anyKey"),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  text: TextSpan(
    text: "This is a heading\n",
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: "Text span in bold",
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () {
            ref.read(sampleServiceProvider).open(Urls.url1);
          },
      ),
      TextSpan(text: " and "),
      TextSpan(
        text: "Text span in italic",
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () {
            ref.read(sampleActionProvider).actionOne();
          },
      ),
    ],
  ),
)

How to differentiate between TextSpan clicks inside RichText widget in Flutter?

Use the following code to click a specific TextSpan in Widget Tests:
RichText richText = ($.widgetByKey(const Key("anyKey")) as RichText);
richText.click("Text span in italic");

with the following extensions:
/// Enables Widget tests to click on a specific text INSIDE text spans/rich texts
extension TextSpanHelper on RichText {
   void click(String innerText) {
      text.visitChildren((span) {
        if (span.toPlainText() == innerText) {
          ((span as TextSpan).recognizer as TapGestureRecognizer).onTap?.call();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
   }
}

T widget<T extends Widget>() => tester.widget(find.byType(T));
Iterable<T> widgetList<T extends Widget>() => tester.widgetList(find.byType(T));
Widget widgetByKey(Key key) => tester.widget(find.byKey(key));

LeanCode Patrol is used.
